# Delete every line with #REF Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete every line containing `#REF` in column A.

My code only works with `value`, and doesn't work with `#REF`.

```
Dim varFindThis As Variant
Dim rngLookIn As Range
Dim f As String

varFindThis = Worksheets("Suivi2").Range("B1")

Set rngLookIn = Worksheets("Suivi2").Range("A:A")

If Not rngLookIn.Find(varFindThis, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then  

    f = Worksheets("Suivi2").Range("B1").Value

'Since i didn't got that clear, here above you must create a code to declare "f" as whatever you want

    Set c = Worksheets("Suivi2").Range("A:A").Find(f)
      Worksheets("Suivi2").Range(c.Address).EntireRow.Delete

End If
```

Comment: Are there any other potential errors on the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) to quickly locate all errors within the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx).

```
on error resume next
with Worksheets("Suivi2").Columns(1)
    if not .specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors) is nothing then _
        .specialcells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
end with
on error goto 0
```

Comment: I just still have one problem, when there is no cellule with error, it's write me a VBA error ''cellule not found''. How can I avoid that?

Comment: You can specify that the process should simply resume processing if an error is encountered. See my edit above.